# How to use this parameter on non-static class property object attribute?

Tags: typescript

I am not sure why, but I have two methods that both use `this` as a type, but one works and one doesn't. I get the following error:

> A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.

```js
export abstract class BaseModel {
  // This does not work (displays above error):
  attributes?: { [key: string]: <T extends FieldsResult<this>>(row: T) => any };

  // This works:
  where<K extends keyof Fields<this>>(field: K, key: '_is_null', value: boolean): this;
}
```

I then extend this `BaseModel` and `override attributes`. However, `row` displays as `any` when it should be the keys from `fields` (This type is returned from `FieldsResult` which works in other places).

```js
export class UsersModel extends BaseModel {
  override fields = { first: '', last: '' }
  override attributes =  {
    // row should contain: {first, last}
    // however, it is `any`.
    full: row => `${row.last}, ${row.first}`,
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to use `this` parameter in this case. [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiBLYAbAJgZwB4AVOUGYAOwLgCEBDfYAWQlxwD44BeOAbwBQcOAG0A0nAyU4Aa2CIIAMzjERAckVY8%20NQF1dALhXrNOAnvG6yICtXx1GLNjjgB%20dFoIkTnnbstcRqoavhZiugDcAgC%20UaCQsAjIqACCMDBQGABGAK4URKTkVDQMTKzs2Fy8fKISUrLySsZq9OmZufl6hs2tGdl5wH6WcLECAPQAVBNwAMIQALZZUq0YENJNpjT01HC97QP4AHRwE2MC8dDwSCgeZvgASoM52DAk1rYljuUuvKVOFQAaOAAVR4t20JC4ADI4Gk%20h1BpCqvwhKIAAqSaRyBTKYHdYEiNGRGJRc7gS67LL4DL0ADG8Fp2EY9j%2032wKOE9CpNPpcFM2iMmDuhG2iA4UU5bX6%20VcRhqImxRmpmUoAHNum8inZwQRHvhnq8YAALDD4DgcAAUUAgAHcggBKHhcUUjKLRARkhIMpn4ezAphQfBs97FFlfZzswTCCAAN2AUEy7DgUGA9Fwa2wiD5vjBNU0gZgRjUaiBPsLcGLrtRsfjidQKbTGaze2lg1zqOEime2CM1ptTrgAAMACR8PuHMvRIGj8f56nRQeo0bRIA)

Comment: Minimal reproducible example, please.

Comment: @vera. I added the link to the question

Comment: I don't think this is possible in TypeScript.

Comment: So would this be a typescript bug maybe?

Comment: Not a bug but a limitation but there are probably workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very similar to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24364

> `this` references the containing type, in this case the object type literal. your solution of defining a type alias is correct.

And in your case `this` would refer to `{ [key: string]: <T extends FieldsResult<this>>(row: T) => any }` which isn't a class. And the equivalent solution (without testing it):

```js
type AttributesType<A> = { [key: string]: <T extends FieldsResult<A>>(row: T) => any }

export abstract class BaseModel {
  // This does not work (displays above error):
  attributes?: AttributesType<this>;

  // This works:
  where<K extends keyof Fields<this>>(field: K, key: '_is_null', value: boolean): this;
}
```

EDIT: Trying to apply to your example, I get [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiBLYAbAJgZwB4AVOUGYAOwLgCEBDfYAWQlxwD44BeOAbwBQcOAG0A0nAyU4Aa2CIIAMzjERAckVY8%20NQF1dALhXrNOAnvG6yICtXx1GLNjjgB%20dFoIkTnnbstcRqoavhZiugDcAgC%20UaCQsAjIqACCMDBQGABGAK4URKTkVDQMTKzs2Fy8fKISUrLySsZq9OmZufl6hs2tGdl5wH6WcLECAPQAVBNwAMIQALZZUq0YENJNpjT01HC97QP4AHRwE2MC8dDwSCgeZvgASoM52DAk1rYljuUuvKVOFQAaOAAVR4t20JC4ADI4Gk%20h1BpCqvwhKIAAqSaRyBTKYHdYEiNGRGJRATXVJtfr5YjJQgpd7Fex-b6VME1ETYoz4PqUADm3QAFFAIAB3IyYO6PfDPV4pDgASh4XG2iBGpIuiXoWW5UHoAGN4HrsIwmV9nNgUcItTr9fBTNpxb5CCqOFErZSEfhXEY4ftqbSYAALDD4V0xARk5LoMES7RSmWEYFMKD4Flh87gS5wI0mkHJ1Pmhl2BxlQuCYQQABuwCgmXYcCgwHouDW2FV9po1TgmhTMCMajUQON3P7ajVqKrNbrqEbzdbqr2VMGbNRwkUz2wRmFIqVcAABgASPjbw7DmDRIFHk897nRPeo0bRIA) which unfortunately doesn't work.

If I look at `type F = FieldsResult<UsersModel>;` I get

```js
type F = {
    first: string;
    last: string;
    full: (row: any) => string;
}
```

and annotating directly with `(row: F)` says

> 'attributes' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

So the cyclic dependency may be the problem. Unfortunately I wasn't able to fix it so far.

Comment: That seems to get rid of the error, but the `row` parameter in `attributes` is still `any` in `UsersModel`.

Comment: Yes, I started to write before you had the example, and unfortunately didn't manage to get it to work with it. See the edit.